# deployment to weblogic node through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, weblogic, devops, devops-services

We are in a process of automating the deployments in weblogic nodes through jenkins.The sequence of steps include shutdown managed shutdown admin do copy the war files start admin start managed server. Issue is coming at start admin server and managed server.Though the admin servers gets started the managed server is erroring out as below. The managed server gets started when we start manually without any issue but facing in sequence steps of starting admin server and starting managed server.

```
<BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user system denied
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user system denied
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:965)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090303]Authentication Failed: User system weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnDelegateException: [Security:090295]caught unexpected exception
at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:251)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASLoginServiceImpl.login(JAASLoginServiceImpl.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
at $Proxy21.login(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.service.internal.WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl$ServiceImpl.login(WLSJAASLoginServiceImpl.java:89)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.authenticate(JAASAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.utils.Delegator$ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(Delegator.java:57)
at $Proxy40.authenticate(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.security.service.WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.authenticate(WLSJAASAuthenticationServiceWrapper.java:40)
at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.authenticate(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:348)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:929)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1050)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Comment: Have you added another Security Provider in WLS Admin console and set that Provider as primary?

Answer (score 0):

please add sleep command and then execute startManaged server command.

Unix - sleep 30s (change according to your time taken by admin server to come up)

Comment: Sleep command is shutting down the server when the sleep time is over. By the way my weblogic is on solaris machine